# Extract array from a string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series that contains:

> [-3.86932793e+02  1.82297039e+01 -5.80108624e+01  3.60803151e+00\n -2.23173279e+01 -1.61694102e+01 -1.91569713e+01 -9.71229354e+00\n  1.04943316e+00 -2.32231360e+00 -1.40624006e+01 -7.31842760e+00\n  9.68115460e+00  2.42948531e+01  5.64715091e+00  2.08459357e+00\n -8.29193170e+00 -5.98514877e+00 -5.60237828e+00  5.11533863e+00\n  4.24665522e+00  2.44113892e+00 -9.27428068e-01  2.42668658e+00\n -1.29403291e+00 -6.17909507e+00  3.12809650e+00  8.99939129e+00\n  8.94010048e+00  8.05541832e+00  5.60370916e+00 -6.52764019e+00\n -9.95711382e+00 -2.02809827e-01  2.57034145e+00 -3.20973926e+00\n -9.36473473e+00 -2.29672003e+00  1.43961641e+00  6.63567513e+00]

How do I turn this into an array I can use for sklearn?

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? It's not clear what you want and what you get.

Comment: I think he wants all the values from the string in an array, like when you split them at the space between and remove the brackets.

Comment: this is not clear. What are you trying to obtain ?

Answer (score 0):

You can call .tolist() on series in pandas to give you a list object.
Since you will use it with sklearn, you most likely want a numpy array, therefore you could also call .to_numpy() which returns a np.array instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this part of code.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    str_ = '[-3.86932793e+02 1.82297039e+01 -5.80108624e+01 3.60803151e+00\n 
           -2.23173279e+01 -1.61694102e+01 -1.91569713e+01 -9.71229354e+00\n 
            1.04943316e+00 -2.32231360e+00 -1.40624006e+01 -7.31842760e+00\n 
            9.68115460e+00 2.42948531e+01 5.64715091e+00 2.08459357e+00\n 
           -8.29193170e+00 -5.98514877e+00 -5.60237828e+00 5.11533863e+00\n 
            4.24665522e+00 2.44113892e+00 -9.27428068e-01 2.42668658e+00\n 
           -1.29403291e+00 -6.17909507e+00 3.12809650e+00 8.99939129e+00\n 
            8.94010048e+00 8.05541832e+00 5.60370916e+00 -6.52764019e+00\n 
           -9.95711382e+00 -2.02809827e-01 2.57034145e+00 -3.20973926e+00\n 
           -9.36473473e+00 -2.29672003e+00 1.43961641e+00 6.63567513e+00]'

    str_ = str_.replace('\n', '').replace(']', '').replace('[', '')

    str_.split(' ')

    array = [float(value) for value in str_.split(" ")]
```

Comment: You mean `array = [float(value) for value in str_.split(" ")]`.

Comment: Yes, I just forgot to convert it to float. Sorry.

Comment: He said he had a pandas series of numbers, not a string. This does not answer the question